# Filtering Data and Naming based on a Variable in a Function in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to write a function that allows me to (A) create a `data.frame` that is named after the arguments in the function. (B) This `data.frame` needs to be a subset of a larger `data.frame` (here `df`). Finally, I need to be able to save the object/`data.frame` out of the function as a printable (etc) `data.frame`.

An example is...

```
Group <- c("Primary Group","Primary Group","Primary Group","Primary Group","Primary Group","Primary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group")
Day <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
Type <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B")
Value <- c(7,3,10,3,9,4,0,9,3,10,1,6,3,4,10,2,3,1)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Group,Day,Type,Value))
Test_Function <- function(Group_Name, Type_Name){
    paste(Group_Name,Type_Name) <- df[(df$Group == Group_Name] & (df$Type == Type_Name),]
}
```

Ideally

```
Test_Function("Secondary Group","A")
```

would return only rows 7-9 in a saved, usable `data.frame` named `"Secondary Group A"`.

Thank you! Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one issue with your dataset. Your primary group values are composed by two separated words. Then, it won't work for naming an object (as far as I know)

Then, if you change the names to make then one word (I show you below, but only change the first one for the example, I asume you have a longer dataset so you may have to do it in R)

```
Group <- c("Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Primary_Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Secondary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group","Tertiary Group")
Day <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
Type <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B")
Value <- c(7,3,10,3,9,4,0,9,3,10,1,6,3,4,10,2,3,1)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Group,Day,Type,Value))
```

Then the following function will do the job:

```
SelFun <- function(Data, Group,Type){
      df <- Data[Data$Group== Group & Data$Type== Type, ]
      assign(paste(Group,Type,sep = ''), df, envir = parent.frame()) 
}
```

Example:

```
SelFun(df, 'Primary_Group', 'A')
```

Will create a data.frame with name Primary_GroupA that will icnlude the selected rows

```
> Primary_GroupA
          Group Day Type Value
1 Primary_Group   1    A     7
2 Primary_Group   2    A     3
3 Primary_Group   3    A    10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
Test_Function <- function(df, Group_Name, Type_Name) {
    return(subset(df, Group == Group_Name & Type == Type_Name))
}

Secondary_Group_A <- Test_Function(df, "Secondary Group", "A");
Secondary_Group_A;
#            Group Day Type Value
#7 Secondary Group   1    A     0
#8 Secondary Group   2    A     9
#9 Secondary Group   3    A     3
```

A few comments:

1. I would make `df` a function argument of `Test_Function`; otherwise `df` inside `Test_Function` needs to be a global variable.
2. We can use `subset` to filter rows; alternatively use `df[df$Group == Group_Name & df$Type == Type_Name, ]`.
3. You need to store the `data.frame` return object of `Test_Function`; here the return object is `Secondary_Group_A`.